# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 12 - 2048

Tags: python

The [project outline](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter12/):

> 2048 is a simple game where you combine tiles by sliding them up,
> down, left, or right with the arrow keys. You can actually get a
> fairly high score by repeatedly sliding in an up, right, down, and
> left pattern over and over again. Write a program that will open the
> game at https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/ and keep sending up,
> right, down, and left keystrokes to automatically play the game.

My solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def main():
    service = Service(r"C:\Program Files\WebDrivers\geckdriver\geckodriver.exe")
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get("https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/")
    try:
        cookie_elem = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, '//*[@id="ez-accept-all"]')
        html_elem = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "html")
    except:
        print("Was not able to find an element with that name.")
    cookie_elem.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        html_elem.send_keys(Keys.UP)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        html_elem.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        html_elem.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        html_elem.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "I couldn't figure out how to make the program end on the game over screen" -- this isn't the place to ask about how to implement new features, it's only for reviewing working code.

Comment: @ggorlen It's not a question. It's a statement expressing thoughts that informed my choices in omitting features, not asking to how to implement one. I thought it was useful for a reviewer as well as because many newbies are recommended the book and look for answers here. I'll remove it if it's still inappropriate, but the code works as specified by the outline.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. Often, people ask questions without actually using a question mark, so the statement can be interpreted to imply "how can I implement this?" in many contexts, usually Stack Overflow, but also here as well.

Comment: time.sleep is generally frowned on in selenium.  Have a look at using explicit waits (see the selenium docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code looks straight-forward and simple enough to me.

The 1 change request I'd make is around the bare except. With exception handling you should always try to be as specific as possible so ideally you'd have something like:

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

...
try:
    driver.find_element(...)
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print(e)
...
```

or at the very least use `except Exception:` instead of `except` because [bare excepts are almost always not what you want](https://compiled.ctl.columbia.edu/articles/bare-except-statements/#:%7E:text=Using%20a%20bare%20except%3A%20statement,almost%20never%20a%20good%20idea.) because you'll ignore *all* exceptions even things like KeyboardInterrupt which means you can't stop the script from running with `Ctrl+C`.

Also even with just `except Exception`, you should really try to capture exception information instead of *swallowing* it so here's a nasty one - you'll catch `NameError`s so in a fresh file try these out:

```py
try:
    some_var_that_doesnt_exist_at_all
    this_should_totally_not_work_and_break
except:
    print("gonna ignore whatever I just caught")

# vs 
some_var_that_doesnt_exist  # you get an obvious NameError & stacktrace

# vs
try:
    some_var_that_doesnt_exist_at_all
except Exception as e:
    print(e)  # prints 'name some_var_that_doesnt_exist_at_all is not defined'
```

`print` will print to stdout and typically you want errors going out into stderr. In a production-ready app, you should leverage `logging` in favor of `print` and you can easily just `logging.exception("a message")` to capture stack traces and error information within an `except` block much better than just `print(e)`.

Finally a suggestion (or what could be considered an extra feature).

#### Swappable configuration

1 thing that sticks out immediately to me is how this code is tightly coupled to a few things that would be nice if they were configurable at runtime dynamically and/or statically at startup. Specifically the driver to use (i.e. FireFox vs Chrome), the path to the driver binary, and the path to your browser executable. This would let you change these variables without having to go and edit code each time. Also you wouldn't have to hardcode the path to your binary which means if someone else tried to run your script on their machine, the code wouldn't just break. You could do this in a number of ways, but here are some:

##### Dynamic configuration at runtime

aka can be changed *after* script startup

Use something like `sys.argv` or [`argparse`](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-guide-to-command-line-arguments-with-argparse-6824c30ab1c3) or [`typer`](https://typer.tiangolo.com/) to read input from a user.

##### Static configuration at startup

aka can configure without code changes before running the script

Read from a config file like json or use a `.env` file which is a bit more conventional. [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) makes using a `.env` file super simple so I'd recommend that.

Comment: Personally I don't think the link you provided for exception handling to be too helpful. Otherwise nice answer. The article doesn't really explain [the exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy). And so doesn't explain what the difference between `BaseException` and `Exception` are. And wouldn't leave the user with the tools to know which exceptions to use. For example `LookupError` is one I use fairly often but, AFAIK, is never raised.